# HTML Template (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking for a small javascript / jquery plugin that can better structure HTML injected content. For example, In my current plugin I need to create templates and it just feels "hacky" injecting this way:

```
var sticker_src = $('<div class="storefront-sticker" style="max-width:'+feature_width+';"><div class="storefront-feature" data-sticker><div class="inner"><span class="flag-icon" style="background-image: url('+iso_flag+');"></span><div class="logo"></div></div><div class="tint"><img src="'+storefront+'" class="bg"></div></div><div class="row pt-1"><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 pr-0"><button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm pull-left" type="button">Find Directions</button></div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6"><a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm pull-right" href="#">View Retailer</button></div></div></div>');
```

I am aware of Handlebars / moustache / underscore but there is a lot of bloat with them, things I do not need. How do I better structure these aspects with js applications?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to create you're own templates and you want to clean up your main script, move the code to a funciton, define that function in another JS file if you really don't want to see it.

```
var createStickerTemplate = function( feature_width, iso_flag, storefront )
{
     return $('<div class="storefront-sticker" style="max-width:'+feature_width+';"><div class="storefront-feature" data-sticker><div class="inner"><span class="flag-icon" style="background-image: url('+iso_flag+');"></span><div class="logo"></div></div><div class="tint"><img src="'+storefront+'" class="bg"></div></div><div class="row pt-1"><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 pr-0"><button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm pull-left" type="button">Find Directions</button></div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6"><a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm pull-right" href="#">View Retailer</button></div></div></div>');
}

var sticker_src = createStickerTemplate( feature_width, iso_flag, storefront );
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are just looking for a way to make the code look a bit more clear right ?

```
var a = 'string from variable ...',
b = [
    '<div>',
         a,
    '</div>'
],
c = b.join('');

console.log(c);
```